# What is the significance of the wrapper method?

Tags: python, decorator

```
def decorator(func):
   def wrapper(func):
     do something before
     func()
     do something later

   return wrapper
```

func = decorator(func) ----> This is my decoarated function
func() does the decorated stuff and gives me the output .

**Why not just decorate it simply ?**

```
def decorator(func):

    do something before
    func()
    do something later

decorator(func)
```

The only advantage I can see is that in one case I get the func object for assigning and re-use . I suppose the question is a bit vague , but I am thinking why do we need to return a function object if our purpose is to just decorate ? I mean whats the advantage ?

Comment: What does "just decorate" mean to you?

Comment: This question also is closely related to how function and variable is in Python . By decorate I mean do something before and after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *have* to return a function object to re-use if you want to ever use the decorated function in more than one place.

In your second example, calling `decorator(func)` calls `func`.  That means that if you want the decorator behavior (i.e., the "something before" and "something after"), you have to call `decorator(func)` every time.

The point of a decorator is that you effectively do `func = decorator(func)` and then, forever after, when you call `func` it automatically invokes the decorator behavior.

Comment: Perfect , re-use is the word . Putting it within the scope as a named object - so that I can re-use .

Answer (score 1):

Consider what the decorator syntax means. This:

```
@decorator
def say_hi():
    print "Hello!"
```

is syntactic sugar for this:

```
def say_hi():
    print "Hello!"
say_hi = decorator(say_hi)
```

So, a decorator basically takes in a function, and returns a new, modified function. Put another way, before decoration, `say_hi` is a function; afterwards, it is still a function…albeit a modified one.

If the decorator was written like this:

```
def decorator(fn):
  return "Something else"
```

Then, before decoration, `say_hi` would be a function, but afterwards, it would have the value "Something else" (a string) instead -- and now it's no longer callable!

Comment: Right so u could say in case you are returning an enchanted set of instructions with no execution involved. In the other you are returning computed result .